# CKEditor 5 manual user input event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor 5 with input event as follows in vue component.

But I need a change event when manually triggered by the user, but it is also triggering during any change in `editorData` from the code side also.

How can I get the event which is triggered by the user and not from the code in CKEditor 5?

```
<ckeditor :editor="editor" @input="onEditorInput" v-model="editorData"></ckeditor>
```